# Docfx custom triple slash tag

Tags: docfx

I want to specify custom /// tag (ex. EcsComponent) that will be added to generated .yml file. And later render some additional info (link to external site) for marked classes. Are the any way to do it? I see some examples of plugins for processing .yml files, but nothing about metadata generation plugins.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/3984 *emphasized text*emphasized text

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [preprocessor](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/howto_create_custom_template.html) and a custom template for this.

The function in `templates/yourTemplate/ManagedReference.extension.js` would look like this

```js
exports.postTransform = function (model) {

  transformModel(model);

  return model;
}

function transformModel(child) {
    if(child.children !== undefined) {

    for (let i = 0; i < child.children.length; i++) { //iterate through every child of the model (if you want to go troughg methods, properties, etc..

      transformModel(child.children[i]);

      for (let j = 0; j < fields.length; j++)
      {
        if (child.children[i].summary && child.children[i].summary.indexOf("<"+ TAG_NAME + ">") !== -1) {
          
            child.children[i]["FIELD_NAME"] = "VALUE"; //value will be set into the model
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then you can render it in `templates/yourTemplate/partials/class.tmpl.partial` like this for example:

```
...
<h5 class="decalaration">{{__global.declaration}}</h5>
...
{{FIELD_NAME}}
...
```

Don't forget to add template to `docfx.json`

```json
"template": [
      "default",
      "templates/yourTemplate"
    ],
```